# CloudFoundryのコマンドでログインするとエラーになります

Tags: bluemix

Bluemixを使用するのに、CFコマンドでログインしたところ、 No org or space targeted, use 'cf target -o ORG -s SPACE' というメッセージが出てエラーとなってしまいます。
どうしたらエラーを回避できるでしょうか？

```
cf login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net
API endpoint: https://api.ng.bluemix.net

Email> ******@gmail.com

Password>
Authenticating...
OK

API endpoint:   https://api.ng.bluemix.net (API version: 2.27.0)
User:           ******@gmail.com
No org or space targeted, use 'cf target -o ORG -s SPACE'
```

Answer (score 1):

Bluemixは現在、米国と英国の2つのデータセンターに存在し、それぞれ接続先が異なります。

米国南部：https://api.ng.bluemix.net
英国：https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net

エラーを見る限り、米国南部に接続した際、組織・スペースが何も無いとのことなので、恐らく、Bluemix上で英国に組織・スペースを作成し、アプリケーションを作成しており、米国南部では何も設定していないのだと思います。

「cf login -a https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net」として英国にLoginするか、Bluemix上で米国南部に移動し、組織・スペースを作成した上で、「cf login -a https://api.ng.bluemix.net」としてログインすることで、問題が解消されるかと思います。